# Angular google maps api for angular project

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-google-maps

I have integrated angular google maps in my project and able to display map by referring to the following tutorial,
https://angular-maps.com/guides/getting-started/,

Here we are trying to add agm-map in HTML and load the map,

I want to get the agm-map object in my .ts file.

How can we get that? Tried all possibilities like adding an id attribute to the agm-map tag, but did not work for me.

Suggest me any new ideas. Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just import it from `@agm/core` using `import { AgmMap } from '@agm/core';`.

You can then use it like any other object.

```
import { Component, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { AgmMap, GoogleMapsAPIWrapper } from '@agm/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  title: string = 'My first AGM project';
  lat: number = 51.678418;
  lng: number = 7.809007;
  // declaration
  map: AgmMap;

  // ElementRef and GoogleMapsAPIWrapper are params in
  // AgmMap's constructor.
  constructor (el: ElementRef, api: GoogleMapsAPIWrapper) {
    // init
    this.map = new AgmMap(el, api);
    // example properties, there are lots more
    this.map.backgroundColor = 'red';
    this.map.scrollwheel = true;
    this.map.draggable = true;
  }
}
```

See the API docs for `AgmMap` [here](https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/components/AgmMap.html).

**EDIT : In response to "adding height to AgmMap."**

Add a height for the `agm-map` element in the corresponding `app.component.css` file.

```
agm-map {
  height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: How to add height for the agmMap?

Comment: Add a height for the `agm-map` element in the corresponding CSS file (updated answer).

Comment: Does not work. Constructor requires additional parameters for `this.map = new AgmMap(el, api)`. `_platformId: Object, _fitBoundsService: FitBoundsService, _zone: NgZone)`. Where to get it all from? What for?

Answer (score 0):

npm install --save @types/googlemaps

declare const google: any;

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps you can follow to integrate google maps in angular

dependencies for package.json file

```
"@agm/core": "^1.1.0",
```

then in your app.module.ts in imports array you need to import below

```
import { AgmCoreModule } from '@agm/core'; // import this and add below to imports array

AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
    apiKey: 'your_api_key',
    libraries: ['places', 'geometry']
})
```

---

next in your component.ts file in which you want to show google map

```
import { AgmMap, MapsAPILoader } from "@agm/core";
declare const google: any;
const place = null as google.maps.places.PlaceResult;


export class MapComponent implements OnInit {

    public searchElementRef: ElementRef;
    lat = 40.16206;
    lng = -96.422414;
    @ViewChild("AgmMap") agmMap: AgmMap;

    constructor(
        private mapsAPILoader: MapsAPILoader,

    ) {
        this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
            this.autocompleteService = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
        });

    }

    ngOnInit() {


        this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
            let autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.searchElementRef.nativeElement, {
                types: 'address'
            });
            autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", () => {
                this.ngZone.run(() => {
                    //get the place result
                    let place: google.maps.places.PlaceResult = autocomplete.getPlace();
                    //verify result
                    if (place.geometry === undefined || place.geometry === null) {
                        return;
                    }
                    let latitude = place.geometry.location.lat();
                    let longitude = place.geometry.location.lng();
                });
            });
        });

    }
}
```

component HTML file

```
        <label for = "City" > Location Name</label>
        < input autocomplete = "off" placeholder = "Location Name" formControlName = "name"
        autocorrect = "off" autocapitalize = "off" spellcheck = "off" type = "text"
        class="form-control" #search >

        <agm-map style = "width:100%;height:100%"[latitude] = "latitude"
        [longitude] = "longitude"[zoom] = "zoom" >
                <agm-marker[latitude]="latitude"[longitude] = "longitude" > </agm-marker>
        < /agm-map>
```